# Не присваивается id элементу (Кнопке), в Android studio , Баг?

Tags: android-studio, java

В findViewId подчеркивает ошибку, хотя я все прописал в activity.xml в R.java нету, может баги?

**Обновление**

```
Button btnPleci;
...
btnPleci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pleci);
```

И вот, подчеркивает ошибку, что посоветуете?

Comment: Приведите код.

Comment: У вас там случайно в коде не `android.R` импортируется вместо `packagename.R`? Проверьте, на всякий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gradle clean build
```

**Обовление**

[image]

Comment: В .xml ид указал android:id"@+id/pleci"

Comment: @grotes, это функция в android studio?Если да, то можно описать, как вызвать ее, менее месяца на андроид студио я.

Comment: @Grotes, спасибо, попробую)